# Popup on mouse hover the word

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am doing a website using asp.net C# and I would like to popup a small window with information as soon as mouse hover a particular word. I know that I have to use jquery but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many plugins out there that will help you achieve what you are looking for.  However it is also very possible to implement this functionality yourself.  I wouldn't be surprised either if some of the plugins you come across also use similar code.

The following is my attempt to demystify tooltip/popup plugin behaviour.

You could wrap the desired word in a `<span>` element and give it a `.hover` class.

```html
<div>
  This is some text with a <span class="hover">special</span> 
  word that has hovercraft capabilities.
</div>
```

Your jQuery ([ver 1.7+](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js)) would look something like this :

```js
$(".hover").on('mouseenter',function(){
  // The popup must be shown here (mouse is over element).
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
  // The popup must be hidden here (mouse has left element).
});
```

I should add here that I am using a great and yet sometimes forgotten capability of jQuery called "chaining".  The `on()` function actually returns the object that it was attached to.  In this case `$(".hover")` - so if I want to call another function on that object I can just add it as another function at the end.  Another example of this would be :

`$("#myElement").text("An error has occured!").css("color","#FF0000");`

That line of code would also at the text to `#myElement` and also turn the colour red.

With regard to your actual popup - I would suggest two things :

1. Have an element at the bottom of your markup (written last so highest index - or manually set the highest z-index)
2. You could also have the popup in a hidden element right next to the element that is supposed to trigger the popup.

Comment: My code as it is here will not give you the functionality - you'll have to insert the popup HTML that you want to use and then toggle the visibility of that element inside those `mouseenter/mouseleave` callbacks...

Comment: are you including a jquery library?

Comment: @Robert yes I am using a jquery library

Comment: @Ryan - have you implemented all the html needed for the popup and implemented toggling the visibility?  Are the `mouseenter/mouseleave` callbacks being fired?

Comment: Also @Ryan, please note the jQuery version - the `on()` syntax is *relatively* new..

Comment: what did you try? can you post a simple jsfiddle.net so we can check the code.

Comment: Fantastic! You are most welcome!  People will always suggest to you some great plugin - most of the time one can DIY with less and more flexible code!  Happy coding! ^_^

Answer (score 2):

What you're after sounds like a 'tool tip'.

The solutions using jQuery are somewhat involved - so I'll just direct you to external resources.

Possible solutions:

- [ToolTip Plugin for jQuery](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/)
- [Build a Better Tooltip with jQuery Awesomeness](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-better-tooltip-with-jquery-awesomeness/)